# Jquery appears undefined in the middle of a working script

Tags: jquery

This is really curious to me and I would like to know your opinion about possible causes for this behaviour. I have a long script in javascript (jQuery) in a Wordpress. At certain point (line 500 more or less) the console outputs the following error:
**TypeError: jQuery(...).each(...) is not a function**
The script is working fine till this point.

The line looks like this:

```
jQuery('.excard').each(function(){
```

After some trials, I added this conditional sentence before the failure line:

```
if(!window.jQuery)
{
    console.log('jQuery is gone??');    
}
else
{
    jQuery('.excard').each(function(){
```

Here comes the funny part: after adding this, I'm not getting any error or messages in the console and the code runs now smoothly.

Can somebody bring some light over this?

Comment: My guess is that the issue is happening with some code that we can't see. If jQuery was gone, you'd be getting an error like "Reference Error: jQuery is not defined", so that's not the issue.

Comment: Your problem isn't `jQuery` becoming undefined, it's that `jQuery('.excard')` isn't returning a jQuery object (and thus does not have a public `each()` method).

Comment: `jQuery('.excard')` should always return a jQuery object, even if no elements are found, so it could be that the method is getting overridden for something else funny is happening. I would try logging `jQuery('.excard')` in your error case and see what it is. Also, remove your conditional to see if it works now - you may have changed something that you fixed it and you didn't realize it.

Comment: If I remove the conditional the error comes back.
I have this conditional above the aforesaid lines:

    if(jQuery('.excard').length > 0){

And this conditional works as well... So the element jQuery('.excard') is there...